# Correct the phone number format using regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have users entering the numbers as

01122449000

- 501122449000
- 5 011 223 39000
  01122449000
- 501 12244 90 00

The correct format is +5<**last 11 digits**>

I have tried with

```
"+5" + tel.match(/\d+/g)[0]
```

Butists giving incorrect results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try stripping whitespace then retaining just the first digit and final 11 digits:

```js
var phone = "5 011 223 39000 01122449000";
var output = phone.replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/^(\d)\d*(\d{11})$/, "+$1$2");
console.log(phone + "\n" + output);

if (/^\+5\d{11}$/.test(output)) {
    console.log("valid phone number");
}
else {
    console.log("invalid phone number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFormattedPhone(a) {
    if (a) return (a = a.match(/\d+/g)) ? "'+2" + a.join("").substr(-11) : ""
};
```

This worked for me.